# Package versions in dpkg.log

Tags: apt, dpkg, logging

I'm trying to decipher the contents of /var/log/dpkg.log. For example this line:

```
2017-09-25 15:19:18 upgrade libpulsedsp:amd64 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.3 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.4
```

What do the two different versions (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.4)  represent? Before and after the upgrade? `apt-get install` can only find the latter version of the package.

Running Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Comment: Pre and post upgrade versions, higher version = new upgraded version.

Comment: use `apt-get changelog libpulsedsp:amd64`

Answer (score 0):

You may easily read the Changelog for a package, thusly:

```
apt-get changelog libpulsedsp:amd64
```

to see what changed in this latest version.